# Dynamic allocation of an array of an indefinite number of structures

Tags: c, dynamic

I know I can dynamically allocate an array of 10 structures in the following way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct studente{
long matricola;
int esami;
};
int main(){
 struct studente *V;
 int i;
 V=malloc(10*sizeof(struct studente));
 return 0;
}
```

But if the number of structures contained in the vector was undefined? That is, if the series of data by which to fill the structures were contained in an external file and the number of structures correspond to the number of sets of data contained in it?

Comment: See realloc. Guess the size; `malloc()`, then `realloc()` as you go.

Comment: You can 1) determine the number of students in advance, 2) use a linked list, 3) use `realloc` which allows you sort of increment the size of your buffer when needed.

Comment: What's a linked list?

Comment: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/08/c-linked-list-example/‎

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps this modified (but unfinished) expansion of your code increases the memory assigned to V as needed:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct student
   {
   long matricola;
   int esami;
   };

int main()
   {
   int rCode=0;
   struct studente *V= NULL;
   int V_elements = 0;
   int V_elementsUsed = 0;
   ...

   V=malloc(10*sizeof(struct studente));
   if(NULL == V)
      {
      fprintf(stderr, "malloc() failed.\n");
      rCode=ENOMEM;
      goto CLEANUP;
      }
    V_elements=10;

   ...

   while(/*Read structure from file succeeds */)
      {
      if(V_elementsUsed == V_elements)
         {
         struct studente *tmp = realloc(V, (V_elements + 10) * sizeof(struct studente));
         if(NULL == tmp)
            {
            fprintf(stderr, "realloc() failed.\n");
            rCode=ENOMEM;
            goto CLEANUP;
            }

         V=tmp;
         V_elements += 10; 
         }

      V[V_elementsUsed]./*field*/ = /*from file*/;
      ++V_elementsUsed;
      }        

...

CLEANUP:

   if(V)
      free(V);

   return(rCode);
   }
```

Comment: Posting just code is not very helpful. Consider adding explanation. Do you thing a code only example is needed in this case where the explanation could be done with minimal code snippets.